# Writing a Recurrence Relation

Tags: algorithm, big-o, recurrence

I've been reading a lot about recurrence relations and I am trying to come up with recurrence relations to these two algorithms:

1. A sort algorithm that chops the list in fourths and repeatedly sorts 
   two of the four segments.
2. An algorithm that does the same as #1, but also looks at half the list each iteration.

I am confused about the two because I am not sure how to represent the second part of #2.

I came up with:

1. 2T(n/4)² + O(n) which leads to nlog(n) based on case 3.
2. 2T(n/4)² + n/2.

I am not sure that I represent algorithm #2 correctly because I can't come up with the Mathematical Analysis to it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might be interested in the so-called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Comment: I don't understand the question in detail; in the first algorithm, is each of the four lists to be sorted recursively and then all of the lists are merged?

Comment: I don't think it is accurate to call #1 a "sort algorithm" if it ignores half of the segments, as then your result won't (necessarily) be sorted.

Comment: Or were you referring to the Master Theorem with 'based on case 3'?

Comment: I was referring to the Master Theorem.

Comment: Your descriptions of the algorithms are sketchy.  Some details are missing.  For example: #1 - how does it merge?  (you assume something O(n), but we don't know).